# Assign manytomanyfield to another manytomanyfield

Tags: django

I have a PaymentOrRefund model.  Negative amounts, obviously, are refunds.  Each payment/refund is registered against one or more invoices.

```
class PaymentOrRefund(models.Model):
    amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
    invoices = models.ManyToManyField(Invoice, blank=True, related_name="payments")
```

variables in the view are:  refund and payment_to_refund

When a payment is made, the invoices against which the payment is registered are chosen client-side.  When a refund is made, then the PAYMENT against which the refund is to be made is chosen client-side, but the invoices for the REFUND are set on the server side.  These invoices need to be assigned from the payment_to_refund.

This does not work:

```
refund.invoices = payment_to_refund.invoices
```

nor does this:

```
refund.invoices.all() = payment_to_refund.invoices.all()
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved:

```
refund.invoices = payment_to_refund.invoices.all()
```